# How to read the variables from a file and set them in batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I have a text file which has two variables CVERSION=1.0.0.0 and PVERSION=1.0. I want the bach script to read these two variables to variables in batch file say, DVERSION and PVERSION respectively. How can I do that?

Comment: Note: The two variables in the file are not in a single line

Answer (score 0):

You could use findstr in a combination with a FOR /F loop.

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=2 delims==" %%V in (`FINDSTR CVERSION myFile.txt`) DO (
  set "myCVersion=%%V"
)
echo %myCVersion%
```

Comment: echoing myCVersion is not giving the expected value. Please review it.

Comment: It works for me. In the file `myFile.txt` is one line `CVERSION=1.0.0.0`. Do you echo the variable in the block or after?

Comment: My script is like this: FOR /F "usebackq tokens=2 delims==" %%V in (`FINDSTR VERSION c:\myFile.txt`) DO (
  set "myCVersion=%%V"
)
echo %myCVersion%

Comment: Look what the `findstr CVERSION myFile.txt` outputs without the FOR loop

Comment: Its giveing both the version strings which are present in the file.  OUTPUT: c:\manifest.txt:cversion=1.0.0 c:\manifest.txt:dversion=1.0

Comment: OUTPUT: c:\manifest.txt:cversion=1.0.0 c:\manifest.txt:pversion=1.0

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18572/discussion-between-user1357950-and-jeb)